# How to interpret number theory result in the language of groups rings and fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

I am following "An Introduction to The Theory of Numbers" by Niven and I am trying to see if I can rephrase the theorems in terms of groups, rings and fields. For example, the theorem
$$(a, m) = 1 \Rightarrow a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$$
can be seen as saying that if $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{m}$ is unit then $x^{\phi(m)} = 1$ (which is obvious because the units form a group of order $\phi(m)$). As another example, rewriting Wilson's theorem this way (and slightly generalizing) turns
$$(p - 1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$
for any prime $p$ into the statement: The product of all units in an integral domain is $-1$.

My question is, how can I do a similar conversion with the statement: $ax \equiv ay \pmod{m}$ if and only if $x \equiv y \pmod{\frac{m}{(a, m)}}$?

Comment: Multiplication by $a$ is a group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{\frac{m}{\gcd(a, m)}}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$. And the statement is saying something about this homomorphism.

Comment: "The product of all units in an integral domain is $-1$." No, certainly not. Look at the units of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, you’re right. Is it true for finite integral domains?

Comment: It is true when the group of units is finite.